# How to edit this string

Tags: iphone, string

Here is a string

```
 "Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 7". "Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 8". Name: Karan.
```

I am trying to make this string like this

```
Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 7, Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 8, Name: Karan
```

I have to search seat no and name in this and before that i need to separate this in array. 
This is the way i am trying.

```
[outStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
//[outStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"outstr:%@", outStr);
NSArray *arrSplit1 = [outStr componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *stringToSearch = @"seat no";
NSString *stringToSearch1 = @"name";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c]    %@",stringToSearch]; 
NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",stringToSearch1];
NSArray *results = [arrSplit1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *results1 = [arrSplit1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate1];
NSLog(@"results:%@", results);
NSLog(@"results:%@", results1);
```

How can i achieve this please guide.

Comment: i think you have these three string 1."Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 7" 2. "Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 8" 3. "Name: Karan". Am i right ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary just a string got from scanning the ticket. It is the complete string i got.

Comment: I think you got your answer so need to expalin it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this it'l give correct output,

```
NSString *stringURL = @"Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 7\". \"Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 8\". Name: Karan.";
    stringURL=[stringURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
    stringURL=[stringURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
    if([stringURL hasSuffix:@","])
        stringURL=[stringURL substringToIndex:[stringURL length]-1];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringURL);
```

O/P:-

```
Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 7, Level1, Row 1, Gold, Seat no 8, Name: Karan
```

in your code replace `\"` with `"`

Comment: @iPhone:based on your reqiurement you can use replace your string with stringURL string in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this methode of NSString.

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:(NSString *)target withString:(NSString *)replacement
```